# How to create hashed index by mgo (golang)

Tags: mongodb, go, mgo

How can I create (or ensure) hashed index with [mgo](https://github.com/go-mgo/mgo) package?

I need a go code to be equivalent with this:

```
>> db.collection.createIndex( { _id: "hashed" } )
```

I have tried using runCommand but there is only ‍`createIndexes` command that want a list of `index specs`. And I have no idea what is that and how I can create `index specs`.

Comment: And I need free beer for the rest of my life. ;) I save money. What have you tried so far?

Comment: @markus-w-mahlberg I have tried using runCommand but there is only "createIndexes" command that want a list of "index specs". And I have no idea what is that..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it as documented at [**`Collection.EnsureIndex`**](https://godoc.org/labix.org/v2/mgo#Collection.EnsureIndex):

> Other kinds of indexes are also supported through that API. Here is an example:

```
index := Index{
    Key: []string{"$2d:loc"},
    Bits: 26,
}
err := collection.EnsureIndex(index)
```

> The example above requests the creation of a "2d" index for the "loc" field.

So basically, you have the format **`$<indexType>:<indexedField>`**, as shown below:

```
package main

import mgo "gopkg.in/mgo.v2"

const (
    db   = "so_hashed_idx"
    coll = "testcoll"
)

func main() {
    var s *mgo.Session
    var err error

    if s, err = mgo.Dial("127.0.0.1:27017"); err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    // An index spec is nothing more than a fancy word for the keys
    // or the key/value pairs handed over to the Key slice of the
    // Index type.
    idx := mgo.Index{
        Key: []string{"$hashed:_id"},
    }

    if err := s.DB(db).C(coll).EnsureIndex(idx); err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
}
```

Building and running the above results in `so_hashed_idx.testcoll` showing its indices as follows

```
> db.testcoll.getIndices()
[
    {
        "v" : 1,
        "key" : {
            "_id" : 1
        },
        "name" : "_id_",
        "ns" : "so_hashed_idx.testcoll"
    },
    {
        "v" : 1,
        "key" : {
            "_id" : "hashed"
        },
        "name" : "_id_hashed",
        "ns" : "so_hashed_idx.testcoll"
    }
]
```

Answer (score 2):

An answer with `runCommand`:

```
func createHashedIndex(session *mgo.Session, collectionName string, indexKey string){
    var result interface{}
    if err := session.Run(bson.D{
        {"createIndexes", collectionName},
        {"indexes", []bson.M{bson.M{"name": indexKey+"_hashed_index", "key": bson.M{indexKey: "hashed"}}}}}, &result); err != nil {
        fmt.Println("Create Index Error:", err.Error())
    } else {
        fmt.Println("Create Index:", result)
    }
}
```